# ScrollTop para pagina com cabeçalho fixo

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde,
Utilizo o código abaixo para ir até o ID servicos abaixo na página:

```
<a class="ff" href="#" onclick="$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#servicos').offset().top}, 500);">SERVIÇOS</a>
```

ele funciona corretamente, porem quando eu dei um `position:fixed` no cabeçalho, o item servicos fica escondido em baixo do cabeçalho.. queria saber se tem como somar o scrolltop + o tamanho do meu cabeçalho (65px), tipo assim: `{scrollTop: $('#servicos').offset().top. + 65px}`

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade seria isso, sem o ponto `.` depois do top, e o valor é negativo, não positivo. Isso deve funcionar descontando o tamanho do cabeçalho *(não precisa colocar o px)*

```
{scrollTop: $('#servicos').offset().top - 65}
```